# How to Create and Access a Separate batch file of a Single

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My Batch File is Getting so Long

Can I make a Some Separate Files for That Same Batch Program

Like

```
@echo off
:top
set /p cmd=
if {condition} goto Condition1
if {conditoin} goto Condition2
if ................ and so on
```

My Batch File Is So Long You Can't Imagine

I want

```
:Condition1
{Planning}
goto top
:Condition2
{planning}
goto top
```

In A Separate Text File

What Can i Do ????

Comment: `if {condition} call condition1.bat` and `goto :top` after all those `if`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all thoses "subroutines" in one file?

```
@echo off
goto %1
goto :eof
:Condition1
{Planning}
goto :eof
:Condition2
{planning}
goto :eof
```

in your main.bat:

```
if {condition} call subroutines.bat Condition1
```