# Batch files calling specific sections from eachother

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write two different batch files that call eachother, but something isn't working
Here is the code of the first batch file(Main.bat);

```
@echo off
:top
set /p cmd=
if {condition} call strings.bat goto Case1
if {condition} call strings.bat goto Case2
and so on.....
cls
```

and my second batch file(Strings.bat);

```
@echo off
:: Go The Hell Out of Here , Nothing To See here.
echo Invalid Command. Retry
call Main.bat goto top
:case1
{My Planning}
call Main.bat goto top
:case2
{My Planning2}
call Main.bat goto top
```

but Main.bat crashes as soon as I input a command(even though it is a valid, correct command). Even though Main.bat crashes, the first line of the second batch-file (Strings.bat) is still reached (i.e

```
:: Go The Hell Out of Here , Nothing To See here.
echo Invalid Command. Retry
call Main.bat goto top
```

)

I think system is not receiving {condition} and just reading it line wise.

Could you please tell me what's wrong in my code

Comment: You seem to guess the syntax of the commands, perhaps you should read first the help of the commands you are using. Try `IF /?` , `CALL /?`and `cmd /?`

Comment: You can't call a Label in another batchfile. What's the Problem with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33615129/2152082)?

Comment: Yes You are right. For that i have to make again  "if {condition} goto case1".and that would be a problem for me

Comment: because you don't use the Label. It is given as parameter  to strings.bat. There you should use it (for example with `goto %1`. Therefore you should call string.bat with one Parameter (the desired Label): `call string.bat case2`. In string.bat. The "return" command would be `goto :eof`. Don't `call` your main.bat again, just return with `goto :eof`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest using a parameter, as @Stephan said in the comments. In Main.bat, use `call strings.bat %cmd%` instead of your if statements, and in Strings.bat use

```
if %1==somestring (
your code here
goto :eof
)
```

Or, even easier, using @Stephan's suggestion, use

```
if %cmd%==somestring (
call strings.bat labelname
goto top
)
```

in Main.bat and use `goto %1` in strings.bat, and make sure the labels in strings.bat are the same as the call parameters in Main.bat but with : before them ofcourse

this will automatically return to the line beneath the call command in Main.bat so you don't need to worry about calling Main.bat